# Can't download package to use PHP SDK for couchbase server

Tags: php, couchbase

I am going through the official documentation of couchbase: `https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html`

What I need is: I want to use php to insert, update, delete on couchbase data.

To configure my local machine I am following the following steps:

1. go to: https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/php-sdk
2. trying to download: http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/php/php_couchbase-2.4.3-7.1-nts-vc14-x64.zip.

But in this URL I am getting the following error message:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
clients/php/php_couchbase-2.4.3-7.1-nts-vc14-x64.zip
</Key>
<RequestId>F7731108CC9B337B</RequestId>
<HostId>
UiCyDZHUww+WX36Lo+AGcX+8tKv0lhMBLUI4PK5+vNSJzwdPlz3Eow0bZBLMax6qmPhk4zQBFsc=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I googled for 2 days. I am apologizing if I am asking such a question which should not be asked here. I am absolute beginner in Couchbase. I am confident with PHP and MySQL. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

N.B: I am using `PHP Version 7.2.0`

Comment: that is some error with the url from the couchbase, probably the file might have deleted. or their s3 service may have expired

Comment: I tried all the links. Is there any better reference to configure couchbase for PHP?

Comment: for me the linux versions of the couchbase do get downloaded, until they (the couch base) fix problems with the links for windows version, you can experiment with linux versions. you may want to install a vagrant environment to do that. actually i recommend swithing to linux

Comment: meanwhile you can create a ticket in this forum https://forums.couchbase.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience, I've fixed links already. We do not provide binaries for PHP 7.2 yet, but you can download them from pecl.php.net or build from sources.